# SQL Server: does ddladmin rights contain datareader and datawriter rights to the database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security

Does `db_ddladmin` fixed database role include `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` rights, so that you don't have to grant those rights explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe so. It should only allow them to run DDL not access tables.

You could make your own role and make it be a member of the db_ddladmin, db_datareader and db_datawriter roles.

Answer (score 4):

Except for `db_owner`, the fixed db roles have no overlap with each other.

You can see this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189612.aspx) ("Permissions of Fixed Database Roles") where the newer GRANT options are listed against the `db_dostuff` roles

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mr. Denny.  The DDL Admin role is exclusive of the Data Reader/Writer roles.  One is for [DDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190667%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and the other two are for [DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).